# React-Router, Problems with gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-router-dom

I'm trying to deploy a create-react-app on GitHub pages. I'm using react-router-dom and I've set homepage to "http://username.github.io/myproject" in packages.json but I got github 404 when I try to enter a path directly "https://username.github.io/myproject/About" if i enter wrong path name it'll direct me to my custom NoMatch page "https://username.github.io/myproject/Abut"

**My App.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import  NavigationBar  from './components/NavigationBar';
import { Footer } from './components/Footer';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { NoMatch } from './NoMatch';
import { Contact } from './Contact';
import { About } from './About';
import { Partners } from './Partners';
import  { Projects }  from './Projects';
import Services from './Services';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <NavigationBar/>
      <Router basename="/project-se">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/About" component={About} />
          <Route path="/Services" component={Services} />
          <Route path="/Projects" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="/Partners" component={Partners} />
          <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**HERE IS MY NAVIGATION COMPONENT**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles= styled.div`

    .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
        color: #fb7840;
        }
    }

    .navbar-toggle-icon  {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;");
        color:#fff;
    }
`;

export default function NavigationBar() {
    return (
        <Styles>
            <Navbar  variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top"  style={{backgroundColor: "#000", color: "#fff", borderBottom: "1px solid #fb7840"}}>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/" style={{ fontSize: "24px", fontWeight: "10em" }}>SARWAR ENTERPRISES</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" className="toggler"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/">HOME</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/About">ABOUT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/Services">SERVICES</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/Projects">PROJECTS</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/Partners">PARTNERS</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/Contact">CONTACT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
        </Styles>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does your code not work when you try to visit the page through Navlink or when you try to change the url manually or both

Comment: i tried both and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set base url

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
</Router>
```

Eg:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar" />
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

Comment: now it's opening the homepage "http://username.github.io/myproject/" but as soon as i clicks any other navlink it gives github's error 404

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed here is my code i replaced BrowserRouter with HashRouter and added exact addresses in Nav.Link

** My App.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import  NavigationBar  from './components/NavigationBar';
import { Footer } from './components/Footer';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { NoMatch } from './NoMatch';
import { Contact } from './Contact';
import { About } from './About';
import { Partners } from './Partners';
import  { Projects }  from './Projects';
import Services from './Services';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <NavigationBar/>
      <Router basename="/project-se">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/About" component={About} />
          <Route path="/Services" component={Services} />
          <Route path="/Projects" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="/Partners" component={Partners} />
          <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here Is My Navigation Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles= styled.div`

    .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
        color: #fb7840;
        }
    }

    .navbar-toggle-icon  {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;");
        color:#fff;
    }
`;

export default function NavigationBar() {
    return (
        <Styles>
            <Navbar  variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top"  style={{backgroundColor: "#000", color: "#fff", borderBottom: "1px solid #fb7840"}}>
                <Navbar.Brand style={{ fontSize: "24px", fontWeight: "10em" }}>SARWAR ENTERPRISES</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" className="toggler"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/">HOME</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/About">ABOUT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/Services">SERVICES</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/Projects">PROJECTS</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/Partners">PARTNERS</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="https://example.com/project-se/#/Contact">CONTACT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
        </Styles>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `React Router` then `BrowserRouter` will not work for now. You can use HashRouter instead.

```
// import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

If you want to use BrowserRouter then add this `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to `Router`

Source: https://medium.com/@arijit_chowdhury/deploy-react-app-with-react-router-to-github-pages-for-free-569377f483f